# How to get the return value of viewcontroller & do a NSString compare?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am a new iOS developer.  I am trying to figure out how to take the return value from a viewcontroller and do a string compare to identify the type of viewcontroller.  My code will hopefully make this clearer:

I have an instance of a viewcontroller called "

```
playTimeVC".  If I do this:
NSLog(@"hello %@", playTimeVC)
```

;

I get the following return:
     2011-08-20 18:26:33.968 Arrangements[37730:207] hello  "<"PlayTimeViewController: 0x58836e0">"

How can I use this return and do some string comparison.  ie:

```
(in Perl)
    if ( [playTimeVC] =~ /PlayTimeViewController/) {
       // This is the one
    }
```

Another question related to what I am trying to do:
When the user clicks on the home button and they are in a certain viewcontroller, is there any method within that controller that is called or does it go directly to applicationWillResignActive?  How about when the user comes back into the app, does it call any method in the VC before resuming?

Thank you in advance.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

The method [isKindOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) of `NSObject` should suit your needs. You can use it like that:

```
if ([playTimeVC isKindOfClass: [PlayTimeViewController class]]) {
    // do something
}
```

About your second question. I'm not sure if the `viewWillDisappear` is called when the user presses the home button. But you can check that by putting an `NSLog` statement into your `viewWillDisappear` and check the console.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.  I tried those methods and it does not appear that those are called upon exit via the home button.